# How do I create a form to upload a file (BLOB) using Spring Roo / Spring MVC

Tags: spring-roo

I want to create an upload form for populating a BLOB datatype using Spring Roo / Spring MVC scaffolding.

Is there any guide over there which I can use? I am using Spring Roo 1.2.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it works.

But take into account that it uses MySQL.

With other DBs you could have problems. Specially with PostgreSQL (you have to read the BLOB data in a transaction because PostgreSQL can store the BLOB internally in several rows) and with ancient Oracle (I had a lot of problems with Oracle 8, I solved them using jdbcTemplate directly)